# GIT. I have path already exist

Tags: git

I an new to one project.

I cloned the repo by using  git clone git@###.###.... 
And seems this command only cloned the master branch.  Since this is a new project. No code is in this master branch. I see all code right now are in 'develop' branch. So i tried to clone develop branch.
So I did: git clone -b develop git@###.###

Then I got error message:

Fatel: destination path $$$ already exists and is not an empty directory.

My question is:
what is right way to do so?
Should I cd .. this directory and create a separate new folder for develop branch?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

`git checkout develop`

and you will be on `develop` branch. When you clone your repository, you should not clone every branch. You can just switch between them.

You can see all your branches by typing
`git branch -r`

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone URL
cd reponame
git branch -r
```

The above command (`git branch -r`) will show what branches are available on the remote server.

You can say `gitk --all --date-order` and see what branches are being actively developed on.  Once you find a branch, say origin/develop, then you can `git checkout develop` and the code should be there.